# Ubuntu MATE Raspberry Pi Kodi Broken

Tags: 16.04, mate, raspberrypi, kodi

When I try to open Kodi in Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on my Raspberry Pi 3 it gives the following messages:

```
$ kodi
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/kodi/kodi-xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
find: ‘/home/caleb/.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/caleb/.config/enchant’: Permission denied Crash report
available at /home/caleb/kodi_crashlog-20160604_133201.log
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: did you look at the crash report?